# How to test that my callback is called from an event?

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, tdd, nunit, moq

I have the following method signature:

```
IAsyncResult BeginWrite(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
```

The callback is hooked into the Completed event like this:

```
public override IAsyncResult BeginWrite(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
  SocketAsyncEventArgs args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs()
  WriteAsyncResult ar = new WriteAsyncResult();
  ar.Callback = callback;
  args.UserToken = ar;
  // ...
  if (callback != null)
      args.Completed += OnSendAsyncComplete;
  // ...

  socket.SendAsync(args);
  // ...
}

private void OnSendAsyncComplete(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
  var ar = e.UserToken as WriteAsyncResult;
  ar.Callback(ar);
}
```

How do I test that my callback is called whenever the args.Completed event when it is raised.
I know that I have to raise it myself but how do I test that my callback was called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you can find a way to raise the completed event yourself (perhaps using an additional abstraction layer), you can do something like this:

A simple way you be to have your async callback in a small class with a property named CallbackCalled. When the callback is called, you set this property to true.

In your test, you call BeginWrite passing the callback method from an instance of the class and then manually raise the event and assert that after that the CallbackCalled property is true.

Comment: I can raise the Completed event because I am mocking the SendAsync method. My problem is that I can't mock the socket event arguments because it's an implementation detail. I'm looking for somethind that I might be able to verify through mocking the socket.

Comment: you mean you can't mock SocketAsyncEventArgs right? That's what I meant by using an additional abstracion layer. Encapsulate the logic to handle the completed event in a separate class that raises an event of its own. You will be able to mock that event in that separate class, and the code that will go untested is simply the code for the event handler (much less likely to fail as the implementation is trivial).

Comment: So what you're saying is that I should have a utility class that accepts SocketAsyncEventArgs for BeginWrite? Oh wait, my code is incorrect.

Comment: Now the code will compile. The Completed event raises an implementation detail. I just have to check that my callback is called.

Comment: Eventually I ended up doing something clever with your advice. Thank you.